# Making a view appear like twitter app does with new tweet (iPad)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

I'm trying to achieve an effect similar to what twitter does when you bring up the new tweet dialogue. They drop down a view from the top, shrinking the other views but still allowing you to interact with all of them if you dismiss the keyboard. It obviously isn't a modal view, but I can't put my finger on what the starting point to do something similar to this would be.

[image: View appears]

[image: Interacting with the other views still]

Comment: You need a hack into the self.view.window hierarchy I believe. It could be achieve with a pageSheet modal if you forced the modal behind your current view. However it may be easier to simple have a container UIView for your content and then have another UIView behind it. Then just handle the animation yourself in your one view controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks straight-forward as a view hierarchy, just cleverly dressed with art.  The bottom is the regular interface, above is a view containing the UITextView with some nice notepad art around it.

One way to achieve this is to hang two subviews under the view controller's main view.  The first child contains the notepad art and the text view.  It's positioned at 0,-NOTEPAD_HEIGHT.  The second child is at 0,0 and occupies the entire parent view's bounds.

The compose button tells the text view to become first responder, and when editing begins...

```
- (void)textViewDidBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView {
    [self setNotepadHidden:NO animated:YES];
}
```

I often make a show/hide method of the following form to rearrange things like this ...

```
- (void)setNotepadHidden:(BOOL)hidden animated:(BOOL)animated {

    NSTimeInterval duration = (animated)? 0.3 : 0.0;
    CGFloat offset = (hidden)? -NOTEPAD_HEIGHT : NOTEPAD_HEIGHT;

    [UIView animateWithDuration:duration animations:^{
        self.firstChild.frame = CGRectOffset(self.firstChild.frame, 0.0, offset);
        self.secondChild.frame = UIEdgeInsetsInsetRect(self.secondChild.frame, UIEdgeInsetsMake(offset, 0, 0, 0));
    }];
}
```

Call with ...Hidden:YES whenever you want to hide it again.  Make sure that the second child's subviews have autoresizing behavior setup so that they do the right thing when their parent shrinks.

I often find the need for one like this, also...

```
- (BOOL)isNotepadHidden {
    return self.firstChild.frame.origin.y < 0.0;
}
```

Hopefully, that's a good start.

Comment: I did it a bit different than what you posted, but you got me on far enough along to make it work. Thanks!